# SSIS Buffer not changing

Tags: sql-server, ssis, buffer

I have a few data flows inside a SSIS package and I'm trying to maximize the buffer.  The machine this runs on has 16GB of RAM and does nothing else (in other words memory is not an issue).

So first off I set SSIS logging on buffertuning and then set DefaultBufferSize to 104857600 (100MB).  Then I set the DefaultBufferMaxRows to 40000 (something I calculated) and ran the package.  The buffersizetuning event says "Rows in buffer type 0 would cause a buffer size greater than the configured maximum. There will be only 20448 rows in buffers of this type.".  Ok so now I know there is a few columns that aren't needed so I remove them.  Some of these columns are varchar(500) and an XML column among of few others.  I go to run the package again and the message I get is "Rows in buffer type 0 would cause a buffer size greater than the configured maximum. There will be only 20448 rows in buffers of this type."   The same exact number!

So my question is, why does the buffer not seem to recognize that there is less data being passed and therefore more rows should be ale to fit into the buffer?

Answer (score 0):

Is your package running in "RunInOptimizedMode" ? Apparently this automtically removes un-used columns.

Trying swithc this package property to false and then run the two scenarios you described.

Answer (score 0):

Try Increasing the DefaultBufferSize from 10485760 to 104857600 for that DataFlow Task and check again. I faced the same problem and increasing the buffer size resolved the Issue+